# git merge commits after fast forward

Tags: git, github

So I have enough knowledge of git to get by however I've been running into an annoyance when using git. When I try to push my commits to github and I haven't checked for someone elses push first I have to do a fast forward pull. So I do `git pull origin master` and then I can go and do my `git push origin master` this is all fine and dandy but then I get a secondary commit about me merging branch master, how can I do this so that I can pull in new files so i can push again but not get the annoying merge commit message on github?

Comment: work on providing some useful information and not just caring about karma or accept or whatever

Comment: @legion Work on not telling people off. You have *absolutely nothing* to gain by alienating someone who's already found your question worth clicking on – especially on SO, which deliberately avoids having a persistent social aspect. It might be frustrating to you to have to "pander to the crowd" like this, but realise that if you expect a prompt answer instead of one from the long tail, the window of time you have to attract attention to your question until it's spammed off the front page is tiny. Every single aspect of your first impression counts, every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two variants:

`git pull --no-commit` - will not create the merge commit

`git pull --rebase` - will rebase your changes on top of the changes in remote master branch, effectively streamlining the history and avoiding merge commit